# Exiting main shell script from awk

Tags: shell, awk

I'have a bash script calling a jar file like this:

```
awk -f fileformat.awk list.txt | while read arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5; do    
    java -jar /bin/2dbf.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5

    if [[ ${?} -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "2dbf.jar finished at: `date "+%F %T"`"
        echo "---------------------------------------------"
    else
        echo "exiting..."
        exit 10
    fi
done
```

the `fileformat.awk` look like this: if the line starts with `#` or it does not have 5 fields exit the program.

```
{ 
    if (NF == 5 && $1 !~ /#.*/) {
        print $0 
    } else { 
        print "incorrect file format"
        "exit 1"
    }
}
```

What I want is that `exit 1` in the `awk` script terminates the whole shell script. but actually it doesn't and the jar file throws exception because of wrong options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `exit` is in quotes in the AWK program, it is spawning an subshell and exiting from *that*. And because you're printing the error message to `stdout`, that feeds the `while` loop. Change your AWK script to this and it should work:

```
{ 
    if (NF == 5 && $1 !~ /#.*/) {
        print $0 
    } else { 
        print "incorrect file format" > "/dev/stderr"
        exit 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. but after the awk script exits the script, `echo ${?}` shows 0 instead of 1.

Comment: @MajidAzimi: That's because it's in a pipe. Try `echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"`. Element 0 in that array is the exit status of the first member of the pipeline.